# Do I need the original files used to create an index in Lucene?

Tags: java, dictionary, lucene

First of all as I explained in my profile, I'm not English native, so I hope you can forgive me if I make some grammar mistakes.

I'm trying to develop with the Apache Lucene API in Java. I'm able to write some index and search methods, but I'm still confused about how it works behind the scenes.

From what I know, Lucene doesn't care about the origin of the data. It just takes the data and indexes it. Let me ask with a simple example:

I want to index words from a .txt based dictionary. Once Lucene has made its indexes, do I need the source .txt dictionary anymore? How, exactly, do the indexes work?

Do the indexes contain the necessary content to perform searches *without* the original source? Or do the indexes only contain directions to where words are stored in the original source .txt dictionary file?  I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have indexed everything, Lucene does not refer back to, or have further need of, any of the source documents.  Everything it needs to operate is saved in it's index directory.  Many people use Lucene to index files, others database records, others online resources.  Whatever your source, you always have to bring in the data yourself (or with some third-party tool), and construct `Document`s  for lucene to index, and nothing about a document says anything about where it came from.  So, not only does lucene not *need* to refer back to original data sources, it couldn't find them if you wanted it to.

Many people's *implementations* do rely on having the original source present.  It's not at all unusual for people to set up Lucene to index everything, but only *store* a file name, or database id, or some similar pointer to the original source.  This allows them to perform an effective full-text search through lucene, while handling storage of the full content to some other system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your explanation clarifies now my point of view.

Comment: To clarify, Lucene can store the source data when you set `Field.Store.YES`, and this is a common thing to do when using Lucene, e.g. for rendering search results in the browser